# El parámetro de un socket es null

Tags: javascript, socket

Estoy teniendo un error en este código y no lo encuentro.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null**

El código es el siguiente:

```
function CountNewImagePerfil(obj){
 socket.emit("CountNewImagePerfil", function (data) {
    var contar = data[0]['contar'];
    if (contar == 0) {
        obj.html(contar);
        obj.fadeOut(500);
    } else {
        obj.html(contar);
        obj.fadeIn(500);
        if (contar <= Glb_nuevoUsuario) {
        } else {
            Glb_nuevoUsuario = contar;
            NotSong_newUsers();
        }
    }
 });
}
```

Este es el archivo al que llama la funcion.

```
require_once("../../assets/functions/main.php");
if ($_POST['type'] == "rechazar") {
$id = $_POST['id'];
if (Usuarios::RechazarImg($id)) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
}
if ($_POST['type'] == "aceptar") {
$id = $_POST['id'];
if (Usuarios::AceptarImg($id)) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
}
```

Comment: ¿en cuál linea marca ese error?

Comment: HOla Rene!! en esta!!     

    var contar = data[0]['contar'];

Comment: ¿y este error te aparece en php? parece un error de javascript

Comment: Si es JS. perdon.

Comment: **data[0]['contar']** es nulo, tienes que verufucar si el dato que intentas acceder es correcto o tiene algún valor

Comment: y como podria hacer esto rene? me ayudas?

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/225396/edit) tu pregunta y agrega el html de donde obtienes ese valor para poder ver el problema

Comment: Estoy arreglando un moco que se mando un programador. Por eso ando perdido. Es que no hace relacion a ningun html. Lo miro mejor y vuelvo, no quiero volverte loco!! gracias Rene!!!

Comment: Rene listo. ahi puse en la pregunta original el html de donde obtiene el valor.. es un php.